# Find the limit of sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+na_{n-1}}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> We have $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+na_{n-1}}{n+1}$

By rearranging we could get $n(a_{n+1}-a_{n-1})=a_n-a_{n+1}$. The nth term between those sequence is not the same so I can't do sth like let $u_n=a_n-a_{n+1}$ and put it in the sequence and see that $u_n$ is arithmetic/geometric progressive so then I could find $a_n$ after finding $u_n$. Is there any way to solve this? Please help

Comment: use $a_{n+1}-a_n = -\frac{n}{n+1}(a_n-a_{n-1})$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be a positive integer, we have for any $ k\geq 1 $ : $$ a_{k+1}-a_{k}=-\frac{k}{k+1}\left(a_{k}-a_{k-1}\right) $$ Thus, for any $ p\in\mathbb{N} $ : $$ a_{p+1}-a_{p}=\prod_{k=1}^{p}{\left(-\frac{k}{k+1}\right)}\left(a_{1}-a_{0}\right)=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{p}}{p+1} $$

Hence : $$ a_{n}=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}{\left(a_{p+1}-a_{p}\right)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ln{2} $$

Comment: How to you evaluate the limit? Riemann sum?

Comment: It's a classic sum, it can be done either with Riemann sums : \begin{aligned} \sum_{k=1}^{2n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2k+1}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2k}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2k}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2k+1}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}{\frac{1}{k}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{n+k}}\\&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x}}=\ln{2} \end{aligned} Or with Taylor expansion for the natural logarithm.

Comment: Ohhh I get it. But why there is a change from n->2n?

Comment: We've just proven that the sequence $ \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}}\right)_{n} $ converges to $ \ln{2} $. The sequence $ \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n+1}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}}\right)_{n} $ does also converge to $ \ln{2} $, well because $$ \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ln{2}+0=\ln{2}  $$ Thus the sequence $ \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}}\right)_{n} $ converges to $ \ln{2} \cdot $

Comment: ohhh I got it now. Thank you so much!